# About Gorenstein ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, gorenstein

Is it true that in a (non-local) Gorenstein ring, every maximal ideal has the same height? It seems a little strange, but I don't see any reason why it shoudn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not true.

Consider a discrete valuation ring $R$ with uniformizing parameter $\pi$ and residue field $k$.
Take for your Gorenstein ring  the polynomial ring $A=R[X] $:  since $R$ is regular, so is $A$ and thus $A$ is *a fortiori* Gorenstein.
Now consider the  ideals $\mathfrak p=(\pi, X)$ and $\mathfrak q=(\pi X-1)$.
We have $A/\mathfrak p=k$, a field,  and $A/\mathfrak q=Frac(R)$, a field too.  So both $\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak q$ are maximal ideals. However their heights are different: $ht(\mathfrak p)=2$  (use $dim A=2$) and $ht(\mathfrak q)=1$ (use Krull's principal ideal theorem)

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is no. Take the product of two local Gorenstein rings of different dimensions; or take any Gorenstein ring $A$ and two prime ideals $P, Q$ of different heights, and no inclusion relation between them and localize at $A\setminus (P\cap Q)$ (you get a semi-local ring whose maximal ideals are given by $P$ and $Q$).

Comment: Very nice!  [Je ne savais pas ce qu'est un anneau de Gorenstein et avais commencé à taper avant de voir votre réponse, mais motus ... J'étais parti du principe qu'un anneau régulier a de toute façon toutes les propriétés de régularité imaginables: Gorenstein, Frankenstein, ... ]

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: ton exemple est très concret:). Regular $\Longrightarrow$ local complete intersection  $\Longrightarrow$ Gorentstein  $\Longrightarrow$ Cohen-Macaulay.

Comment: Yes, I had checked the definition in Matsumura before posting my answer. I suppose it will take some time before I have a gut feeling for Gorenstein, which seems a very weak concept. Any hint for helping me understand it?   [Ah, et je vais donc avoir le plaisir de te tutoyer!]

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: I'm not acquainted with Gorenstein, Frankenstein... sorry. For me, it means the dualizing complex is an invertible sheaf. [Je pense que tu me tutoyais déjà il y a longtemps]